# Redireccionar a SSL

Tags: web, ssl, https, dominio

He añadido mi certificado SSL a mi web y funciona bien. Lo que pasa es que debo buscar expresamente https://www.nombredominio.com, y eso es poco efectivo. Si la busco tal cual, sin el https://, me sale la versión no segura de mi web.

¿No hay ninguna forma de, cuando alguien busque directamente nombredominio.com directamente se abra la página segura (con SSL)?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones:

**1) Virtual Host:** puedes modificar tu archivo de virtual host e indicar alli que todas las peticiones por el puerto 80 vayan a tu web por el puerto **443**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.ejemplo.com
    Redirect / https://www.ejemplo.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.ejemplo.com
    # ... tu configuración SSL va aquí si tienes
</VirtualHost>
```

**2) Index.php:** si en tu servidor tienes instalado **PHP** puedes usar en la carpeta raíz a donde tu dominio esta apuntando y colocar un archivo **index.php** para que redirecciones a la tu dominio con el puerto **443:**:

```
<?php 
  header("Location: https://ejemplo.com");
  die();
?>
```

**3) .htaccess:** puedes crear un archivo de configuración para Apache en la carpeta raíz en donde tu dominio esta apuntando para que te redireccione:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ejemplo.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu archivo .htaccess puedes usar este código para que todo el trafico de tu sitio se redireccione a Https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```